# VBA - change of the XValues with variables

Tags: excel, vba, charts, visualization

I am completely new in the realm of programming and am starting to learn VBA for Modelling financial scenarios in Excel.
Now I have a question regarding the change of the XValues of Chart in order to change the dates presented to me of a given data Set.

I use Variables that store the first and last row number of the series which I want to use to give VBA a varying range to choose the XValues from based on how I define the variables.
The variables are defined as integers.

My code:

```
Sheets("Result").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Portfolio").Range(Cells(RangeStart, 1), Cells(RangeStop, 1))
```

It would be very kind for you to explain to me what is wrong with the second row and how I can solve the "application-defined or object-defined error".

I thank you all in advance,

Nick

Comment: for a start you need to fully qualify the Cells by putting sheet name in front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Fully qualify `Cells` with the worksheet name

```
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Portfolio").Range(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Portfolio").Cells(RangeStart, 1), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_Portfolio").Cells(RangeStop, 1))
```

2) Should also be sure there is a series(1) to add to and for some versions it is better to use `SeriesCollection` rather than `FullSeriesCollection`.

3) Use Long rather than Integer to avoid potential overflow.

Example below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim RangeStart As Long
    Dim RangeStop As Long

    RangeStart = 1
    RangeStop = 5
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_Portfolio")

    Worksheets("Result").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate '<== Is this ActiveWorkbook or ThisWorkbook?
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries '<=  added for demo only to ensure present
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ws.Range(ws.Cells(RangeStart, 1), ws.Cells(RangeStop, 1)) '< x
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ws.Range(ws.Cells(RangeStart, 1), ws.Cells(RangeStop, 1)) ' < y copied for test purposes only
End Sub
```