# Index Function not working when used as a reference for plotting

Tags: excel, vba

Forgive me because this is my first post. I am trying to have my data auto-crop my data at a certain point for a plot I am making. The first point is always the same and I can find the reference for the final point using the Index function. The top code is how I defined my values initially which included all of the data in columns `E` and `D` in a large range that encompassed all of the data. When I replaced the `"$E$10000"` terms with my index function I could not get the code to work. Any help identifying the error in the second lines of code shown below would be much appreciated.

Code that works but does not crop data:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Sheet123'!$E$14:$E$10000"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Sheet123'!$D$14:$D$10000"
```

Code that should crop data, but it does not work at the time being:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Sheet123'!$E$14:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(J19,D:D,0))" 
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Sheet123'!$D$14:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(J19,D:D,0))"
```

Comment: The question is what values do you have in column D? What does `INDEX(E:E,MATCH(J19,D:D,0)` return? Put that formula into a cell and tell us the value it returns. If the values in D are no addresses like `$D$10000` this cannot work. `Index` returns values of cells. • If you need further help please show example data. A screenshot might help too.

Comment: This might help [VBA - change of the XValues with variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354578/vba-change-of-the-xvalues-with-variables)

Comment: I don't think you can use a function inside a range description. But you can use the [OFFSET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) function to resize the required range. `=OFFSET('Sheet123'!$E$14,0,0,MATCH(J19,D:D,0)-13)`